# How to use display table-cell auto width 100% with ul > li > div

Tags: html, css

I want to create table without `<table>` element and replace with

table to "ul"

tr to "li"

td to "div"

but all table-cells width not equal with before row

CSS code

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    display: table;
}
.td {
    float: none;
    width: 1%;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="table">
<li class="tr">
        <div class="td">1</div>
        <div class="td">aaaa</div>
        <div class="td">zzzzzzz</div>
    </li>
    <li class="tr">
        <div class="td">2</div>
        <div class="td">nnbnb</div>
        <div class="td">;;;;;;;</div>
    </li>
    <li class="tr">
        <div class="td">3</div>
        <div class="td">qqssqqq</div>
        <div class="td">zzzzzsdafsfzz</div>
    </li>
    <li class="tr">
        <div class="td">4</div>
        <div class="td">aasdfs</div>
        <div class="td">zzzzzzz</div>
    </li>
    <li class="tr">
        <div class="td">5</div>
        <div class="td">ddssssssddd</div>
        <div class="td">zzzzzzz</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

or Visit https://jsfiddle.net/pirune/k2abyf64/18/

Comment: You forgot to style the li elements.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following CSS:

```
.tr {
  display: table-row;
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bd8ceuvj/